# Monit to use with virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, monit

I want to monitor django server using monit. However, it won't let me to run "python manage.py runserver" because it is environment specific to the virtualenv that i use.

So i want to do..

```
workon myvirtualenv
```

and then run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

however I can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Can you string the commands together for your start command?

```
"workon myvirtualenv && python manage.py runserver"
```